# Web-scrape. BeautifulSoup. Multiple Pages. How on earth would you do that?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hi I am a Newbie to programming. So I spent 4 days trying to learn python. I evented some new swear words too.
I was particularly interested in trying as an exercise some web-scraping to learn something new and get some exposure to see how it all works.
This is what I came up with. See code at end. It works (to a degree)

But what's missing?

1. This website has pagination on it. In this case 11 pages worth.  How would you go about adding to this script and getting python to go look at those other pages too and carry out the same scrape. Ie scrape page one , scrape page 2, 3 ... 11 and post the results to a csv?
   https://www.organicwine.com.au/vegan/?pgnum=1

   https://www.organicwine.com.au/vegan/?pgnum=2

   https://www.organicwine.com.au/vegan/?pgnum=3

   https://www.organicwine.com.au/vegan/?pgnum=4

   https://www.organicwine.com.au/vegan/?pgnum=5

   https://www.organicwine.com.au/vegan/?pgnum=6

   https://www.organicwine.com.au/vegan/?pgnum=7

8, 9,10, and 11

2. On these pages the images are actually a thumbnail images something like 251px by 251px.
   How would you go about adding to this script to say. And whilst you are at it follow the links to the detailed product page and capture the image link from there where the images are 1600px by 1600px and post those links to CSV
   https://www.organicwine.com.au/mercer-wines-preservative-free-shiraz-2020
3. When we have identified those links lets also download those larger images to a folder
4. CSV writer. Also I don't understand line 58
   for i in range(23)
   how would i know how many products there were without counting them (i.e. there is 24 products on page one)

So this is what I want to learn how to do. Not asking for much (he says sarcastically) I could pay someone on up-work to do it but where's the fun in that? and that does not teach me how to 'fish'.

Where is a good place to learn python? A master class on web-scraping. It seems to be trial and error and blog posts and where ever you can pick up bits of information to piece it all together.
Maybe I need a mentor.
I wish there had been someone I could have reached out to, to tell me what beautifulSoup was all about. worked it out by trial and error and mostly guessing. No understanding of it but it just works.

Anyway, any help in pulling this all together to produce a decent script would be greatly appreciated.
Hopefully there is someone out there who would not mind helping me.

Apologies to organicwine for using their website as a learning tool. I do not wish to cause any harm or be a nuisance to the site

Thank you in advance
John

code:

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.organicwine.com.au/vegan/?pgnum=1"
response = requests.get(URL)
website_html = response.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(website_html, "html.parser")

product_title = soup.find_all('div', class_="caption")
# print(product_title)

winename = []
for wine in product_title:
    winetext = wine.a.text
    winename.append(winetext)
    print(f'''Wine Name: {winetext}''')
# print(f'''\nWine Name: {winename}\n''')

product_price = soup.find_all('div', class_='wrap-thumb-mob')
# print(product_price.text)

price =[]
for wine in product_price:
    wineprice = wine.span.text
    price.append(wineprice)
    print(f'''Wine Price: {wineprice}''')
# print(f'''\nWine Price: {price}\n''')


image =[]
product_image_link = (soup.find_all('div', class_='thumbnail-image'))
# print(product_image_link)
for imagelink in product_image_link:
    wineimagelink = imagelink.a['href']
    image.append(wineimagelink)
    # image.append(imagelink)
    print(f'''Wine Image Lin: {wineimagelink}''')
# print(f'''\nWine Image: {image}\n''')
#
#
# """ writing data to CSV """
# open OrganicWine2.csv file in "write" mode
# newline stops a blank line appearing in csv

with open('OrganicWine2.csv', 'w',newline='') as file:
  # create a "writer" object
  writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
  # use "writer" obj to write
  # you should give a "list"
  writer.writerow(["Wine Name", "Wine Price", "Wine Image Link"])
  for i in range(23):
    writer.writerow([
      winename[i],
      price[i],
      image[i],
    ])
```

Comment: to get pages you can do `for i in range(11): url = f"https://www.organicwine.com.au/vegan/?pgnum={i+1}"`

Comment: I think your question is better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: to get how many wines you have you can do `len(winename)`

Comment: Hi Boris, Thank you for taking the time to respond. The Range part and Len(winename) is great I can use that. Also thank you for the advice re the codereview.stackexchange.com commmunity. I will take a look and pose this there. thank you.

Comment: Hi Boris , Thank you for your help I am so grateful to you. Just to let you know the outcome, I reached out to codereview.stackexchange.com they where so rude and unhelpful.."You should Know Code ....!" Maybe I was just unlucky and got the most unhelpful person on the planet. I'll keep looking for more help and encouragement.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. If you undelete your question on code review and let me know, I'll answer it and rewrite your code.

Comment: One thing I would suggest in response to your "It seems to be trial and error and blog posts" is that you approach learning to code and learning Python more systematically and take the time to either read a book about it or take an online course. You can read through [the official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) or the book Learn Python the Hard Way is a common recommendation. It will save you a lot of time in the long run to actually understand what you're doing.

Comment: @Boris Code review does not explain what code does, it indicates that the OP didn't write the code.

Comment: Hi Boris, how's things?
I checked out both scripts and this is a good way to see how things work and learn from. 
Just by looking at the code examples you have tweaked and provided has helped me immensely to understand. I'll still need to study these a bit more, but it is much clearer on what it is doing and it teaches me how to find the various elements to home in on. And now I understand how the range works page number works. I would have struggled trying to work that out. (easy when you know how)

Comment: The website on page 10 had an Item that was 'Sold Out' so the code threw up an error saying 'there is no Span Text here' and came to a stop.Is there a good way to say if you don't find 'the text you are looking for' just put " " and move on to the next.

But this has helped me a lot in understanding and I'll try different options and searches (play with the code) and see what other STOPs I might come across

So I have signed up to an online course on Udemy 100 days of code Python Pro bootcamp this will be a good place to start from beginner to advanced this should keep me busy and learning

Comment: I will read through the official Python tutorial  , thank you for pointing me in the right direction and thank you for the recommendation on the book Python the Hard Way. That looks quite good. 

Ok. You have been a great help and provided great support. I am very grateful to you for that. 
This community help is working

John


PS I wont bother re-posting to codereview.stackexchange.com  that place comes across as aggressive and unhelpful.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, to do pagination, instead of `for i in range(1, 100)` which is a hardcoded way of paging, it's better to use a `while` loop to dynamically paginate all possible pages.

"While" is an infinite loop and it will be executed until the transition to the next page is possible, in this case it will check for the presence of the button for the next page, for which the CSS selector ".fa-chevron-right" is responsible:

```py
 if soup.select_one(".fa-chevron-right"):
        params["pgnum"] += 1                # go to the next page
else:
     break
```

To extract the full size image an additional request is required, CSS selector ".main-image a" is responsible for full-size images:

```py
full_image_html = requests.get(link, headers=headers, timeout=30)
image_soup = BeautifulSoup(full_image_html.text, "lxml")
        
try:
    original_image = f'https://www.organicwine.com.au{image_soup.select_one(".main-image a")["href"]}'
except:
    original_image = None
```

An additional step to avoid being blocked is to [rotate user-agents](https://serpapi.com/blog/how-to-reduce-chance-of-being-blocked-while-web/#rotate-user-agents). Ideally, it would be better to use residential proxies with random user-agent.

[`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) can be used to extract data in CSV format:

```py
pd.DataFrame(data=data).to_csv("<csv_file_name>.csv", index=False)
```

For a quick and easy search for CSS selectors, you can use the [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension (*not always work perfectly if the website is rendered via JavaScript*).

Check code with pagination and saving information to CSV in [online IDE](https://replit.com/@denisskopa/scrape-organicwine-with-pagination-bs4#main.py).

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, json, lxml
import pandas as pd

# https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.60 Safari/537.36",
  }
    
params = {
    'pgnum': 1           # number page by default 
  }

data = []

while True:
    page = requests.get(
        "https://www.organicwine.com.au/vegan/?",
        params=params,
        headers=headers,
        timeout=30,
    )
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "lxml")

    print(f"Extracting page: {params['pgnum']}")

    for products in soup.select(".price-btn-conts"):
        try:
            title = products.select_one(".new-h3").text
        except:
            title = None
        try:
            price = products.select_one(".price").text.strip()
        except:
            price = None
        try:
            snippet = products.select_one(".price-btn-conts p a").text
        except:
            snippet = None
        try:
            link = products.select_one(".new-h3 a")["href"]
        except:
            link = None

        # additional request is needed to extract full size image
        full_image_html = requests.get(link, headers=headers, timeout=30)
        image_soup = BeautifulSoup(full_image_html.text, "lxml")
        
        try:
            original_image = f'https://www.organicwine.com.au{image_soup.select_one(".main-image a")["href"]}'
        except:
            original_image = None
        
        data.append(
            {
                "title": title,
                "price": price,
                "snippet": snippet,
                "link": link,
                "original_image": original_image
            }
        )

    if soup.select_one(".fa-chevron-right"):
        params["pgnum"] += 1
    else:
        break

# save to CSV (install, import pandas as pd)
pd.DataFrame(data=data).to_csv("<csv_file_name>.csv", index=False)
print(json.dumps(data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Example output:

```json
[
    {
    "title": "Yangarra McLaren Vale GSM 2016",
    "price": "$29.78 in a straight 12\nor $34.99 each",
    "snippet": "The Yangarra GSM is a careful blending of Grenache, Shiraz and Mourvèdre in which the composition varies from year to year, conveying the traditional estate blends of the southern Rhône. The backbone of the wine comes fr...",
    "link": "https://www.organicwine.com.au/yangarra-mclaren-vale-gsm-2016",
    "original_image": "https://www.organicwine.com.au/assets/full/YG_GSM_16.png?20211110083637"
  },
  {
    "title": "Yangarra Old Vine Grenache 2020",
    "price": "$37.64 in a straight 12\nor $41.99 each",
    "snippet": "Produced from the fruit of dry grown bush vines planted high up in the Estate's elevated vineyards in deep sandy soils. These venerated vines date from 1946 and produce a wine that is complex, perfumed and elegant with a...",
    "link": "https://www.organicwine.com.au/yangarra-old-vine-grenache-2020",
    "original_image": "https://www.organicwine.com.au/assets/full/YG_GRE_20.jpg?20210710165951"
  },
  #...
]
```